# "has not been declared" error with inheritance of class templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

The following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    using A_int = int;               // A_int type declared here
    virtual void foo(A_int) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : public A {

};

template <typename T>
struct C : public B<T> {
    void foo(A_int) override {
        std::cout << "all good\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
  C<int> c;
  c.foo(1);
}
```

produces this error:

```
15:14: error: 'A_int' has not been declared
```

The same code without the use of templates compiles fine. Could anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to say where `A_int` comes from:

```
void foo(typename B<T>::A_int) override {
    std::cout << "all good\n";
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/HHCaBH).

Answer (score 0):

A_int has to accessed over the class specifier A::, so it becomes A::A_int

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    using A_int = int; 
    virtual void foo(A_int) = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : public A {

};

template <typename T>
struct C : public B<T> {
    void foo(A::A_int) override {
        std::cout << "all good\n";
    }
};


int main()
{
  C<int> c;
  c.foo(1);
}
```

Comment: can I do anything if A is declared in a file that I can't modify?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, you can access it with A::A_int